# How would I write a function to replace things?

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace, str-replace

I am trying to work on an assignment in python and am completely stumped. Please help.

Write a function called myReplace() that performs a task similar to the string.replace() method. This function should take three parameters: The first, called the content string, can be any string. The second, called the token, should be a string containing a single character which is to be replaced in the content string. The third, should denote the new character(s) that will be in the resulting string. The function should return a new string with the token letter(s) replaced by the new characters. Your function should ensure valid input is provided, and return the original string if not. Note: You may not use the built-in replace() method for this question.
E.g.:

```
>>> result = myReplace("Hello world!",'l','q')

>>> print(result)
  Heqqo Worqd!

>>> result2 = myReplace("This is a sentence."," ","\t")

>>> print(result2)
  This     is     a     sentence.

>>> result3 = myReplace("Failure case","ail","oil") #only needs to work for single letter tokens

>>> result3
  'Failure case'
```

I'm not looking to get anyone to write this for me. But I have no idea what to do

Comment: Can we see your current `myReplace` function?

Comment: Are you allowed to use regular expressions?

Comment: Hint: try to assign a string to a variable `repstring = "Hello World"` and see what happens when you do `repstring[0]`

Comment: Take a look at related [string methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) `find`, `rfind`, `index`, and `rindex`.

Comment: `myReplace=lambda c,t,r:"".join([x,r][ x==t ] for x in c)` a good thing to do for starters is to open your textbook and go to class, take notes, ask questions of the teacher(or classmates) if you dont understand the concepts ... otherwise future lessons that will build off this concept will be locked to your brain

Answer (score 1):

```
def myReplace(s,old,new): new.join(s.split(old))
```

is a small version of what you want. You will want to add error checking and all that with things like `type(s)` or `len(old)` then returning `s` if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
def replace(stringname,oldletter,newletter):
    newstring = ''
    for i in range(len(stringname)):
        if stringname[i] == oldletter:
            newstring = newstring + newletter
        else:
            newstring = newstring + stringname[i]
    return newstring

stringorig = "Hello World!"
displayname = replace(stringorig,'l','o')
print displayname
```

You take the index of the string and compare it to the letter you need to change it to. I am sure R Nar's answer is the the shortest and best answer but more answers can't hurt.